# Generate random number between 1 and 3 / including 1 decimal place

Tags: c#, random, unity-game-engine, int

I can generate a random number between 1 and 3 fairly easy.

```
float x = Random.Range(1, 3);
```

But I am trying to generate a random number between 1 and 3, including 1 decimal place.
i.e 1.0, 1.1, 1.2 - 2.8, 2.9, 3.0
Any help appreciate. I am finding no easy function to do this.

Note - I am using .cs script in Unity

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can multiply the result like this:

```
float result = rnd.Next(10, 31) * .1f;
```

This will result in a range from `1.0` to `3.0`, stepping by `.1`.

Comment: Change it to rnd.Next(10, 31), the upper limit is exclusive, not inclusive.

Comment: Ya, I just released that.  Updating.

Comment: Sorry I should have noted I am using a script in the Unity program to do this. Getter the error, 'UnityEngine.Random' does not contain a definition for 'Next' and not extension method 'Next' of type 'UnityEngine.Random' could be found.

Comment: Can't say I'm familiar with Unity, but it it's anything like C#, the concept should still work.  Use your original method name `Random.Range`, but update the values and multiply like I mentioned. It should work.

Comment: I think its working as its not throwing an error, now have code        double result = Random.Range(-41, 41) * .1 Problem is the method Im putting it into 'transform.position', needs a float....The best overloaded method match for 'UnityEngine.Vector3(float,float, float)' has some invalid arguments

Comment: Ok, use a float instead: `float result = Random.Range(-41, 41) * .1f`

Comment: Got it working with this, had to do a little trick to input float but method worked. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This seems solid.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        float fMyNumber = 0;

        Random rnd = new Random(Guid.NewGuid().GetHashCode());
        for (int j = 0; j < 20; j++) {
            fMyNumber = rnd.Next(1, 4);
            fMyNumber += ((float)rnd.Next(10)) / 10;
            Console.WriteLine(fMyNumber.ToString("0.0"));
        }
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply add decimal numbers to your original code:

```
Random.Range(1.0, 3.0);
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the variable you are applying the Random.Range() method to is a float and not an int. Also where using the method make sure you put f after each float e.g. Random.Range(1.0f, 3.0f).

Random.Range is maximally exclusive so you may want to use 3.1f to include up to 3.0f.

I know this thread is old just thought I'd try and help for anyone else looking at it.

Answer (score 0):

For those using Unity, use System.Random.

For instance:

```
System.Random rnd = new System.Random();
```

Unity has it's own random object that's getting in the way.